# Getting sub pixel accuracy from mouse events

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get a more precise x and y position for mouse events? I'm thinking about graphics that show lots of data in a physically limited space.

For instance a color picker or waveform data can have lots of data, but the width of the page only has so many pixels.

Comment: The mouse isnt accurate enough?

Comment: a pixel is a pixel...either you hit it with your click....or not

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX

`var pageX = MouseEvent.pageX;`

> This property was originally specified in the Touch Events
>   specification as a long integer, but was redefined in the CSSOM View
>   Module to be a double-precision floating-point number to allow for
>   subpixel precision.